# After subtracting decimal numbers, too many digits are displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I subtract `300.7 - 245.8`, it is displaying result as `54.89999999999998`
and `400 - 364.7` as `35.30000000000001`.

Comment: It is because Javascript does odd things with floats and math. you will need to round the number off or split the decimal place into an integer. for a fill description into this please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` on your result, this should round it to 2 numbers.

Comment: Is there any permanent solution. Because, i am using these subtraction concept in so many files. If i use this, i have to edit in all files

Comment: You can make a function called substract and use that every time you want to subtract something. Then place this round down in the method.